# Why does a FOR loop in batch file shows directories not matching the wildcard pattern?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

This batch file:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo off
for %%a in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
    for /D %%f in (K:\cases\%%a*) do (
          echo Found directory starting with-%%a directory=%%~nxf
    )
)
```

Results in:

```
Found directory starting with-b directory=070441_0001_LAW
Found directory starting with-d directory=DELETE_012216_0118
Found directory starting with-e directory=eh_TEST_20151009
Found directory starting with-f directory=029947_0030_LAW
Found directory starting with-f directory=FB_Testing_Case
Found directory starting with-k directory=070441_0001_LAWPROD
Found directory starting with-l directory=060662_0012_LAW
Found directory starting with-l directory=LAW_68_Update
Found directory starting with-m directory=064451_0014_LAW
Found directory starting with-m directory=064451_0015_LAW
Found directory starting with-o directory=063113_0028_LAWPROD
Found directory starting with-o directory=072920_0001_LAWEDA
Found directory starting with-p directory=064451_1000_007_LAWPROD
Found directory starting with-q directory=063113_0028_LAWEDA
Found directory starting with-t directory=072920_0001_LAWPROD
Found directory starting with-t directory=064451_1000_005_LAWPROD
Found directory starting with-t directory=064451_1000_006_LAWPROD
Found directory starting with-t directory=TEST_06222016
Found directory starting with-u directory=060662_0012_LAWPROD
```

Why are directories displaying that don't start with their appropriate letter?

Comment: What do you see if you run in a command prompt window `dir K:\cases\b* /AD /X` to get displayed all directories starting with letter B in any case and getting displayed also short 8.3 name? Does short 8.3 name of directory `070441_0001_LAW` start with `B`?

Comment: Is that the full content of your actual batch file? I'm a bit suspicious about some of those letters (e.g. "f", "o", "t", etc) being listed more than once, as if the first FOR loop was stuttering...

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It's inappropriate to edit your post to say *Yes, you solved it*. If you'd like @Mofi to post an answer, ask using the proper syntax (as I just did). If you want to post an answer yourself, do so in the space provided below for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On searching for files or directories with a wildcard pattern the low level Windows kernel routine does not only take the long file/directory name into account, but also the short 8.3 file/directory name.

This produces often unexpected results. One method to avoid false positives because of short 8.3 file/directory name matching the wildcard pattern although the long file/directory name does not match the pattern is to extra check the long name against the pattern, for example with using **FINDSTR**.

This extra check can be done for this case very easily without **FINDSTR** as it must be only verified that the long directory name really starts with the expected letter case-insensitive.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
    for /D %%D in (K:\cases\%%a*) do (
        set "DirectoryName=%%~nxD"
        if /I "!DirectoryName:~0,1!" == "%%a" (
            echo Found directory starting with %%a - directory=%%~nxD
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

`dir /AD /X` can be used to see the short names of directories.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`